# Empty data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, sentiment-analysis

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Date", "Time", "Contact", "Message"])
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

data=df.dropna()
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sentiments=SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
data["positive"]=[sentiments.polarity_scores(i)["pos"] for i in data["Message"]]
data["negative"]=[sentiments.polarity_scores(i)["neg"] for i in data["Message"]]
data["neutral"]=[sentiments.polarity_scores(i)["neu"] for i in data["Message"]]

data.head(50)
```

This is showing an output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Time, Author, Message, Positive, Negative, Neutral]
Index: []
```

I tried changing the names of colums but it didn't worked.
Instead it should have created a data table.

Comment: what is `data`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.